# Hair particle system moves position when loading

Tags: particles, hair

I am using Blender 2.79b in cycles render trying to create a character model with realistic hair and eyebrows.  I have set up my hair using a vertex group for the scalp, and the eyebrows were placed using the add tool and X mirror.  Standard hair settings;

- Hair dynamics unchecked
- Velocity settings default
- Rotation unchecked
- Physics settings default
- Render settings default with B-Spline at 6 steps
- Display rendered with 6 steps
- Children interpolated, display 25, render 25, long hair checked (unchecked for eyebrows)
- Field weights default
- Force field default
- Vertex groups density set for scalp
- Custom properties default
- Textures default
- Cycles hair settings with root at 0.20 and tip at 0 with close tip unchecked

After combing the hair into the position I want, I can render an image and it looks good.  I save the .blend file.  If I close the program and load the file I encounter a few problems.

1. The hair is now completely messed up and out of position.
2. Some of the hair parents have moved position, away from the vertex group in random places on the model, and sometimes floating in mid air away from the model.
3. The eyebrow I placed appears to stay in position, but the mirrored eyebrow is randomly scattered.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: problem is for the sake of performance we can't have same subdivision level in view port and render .

Answer (score 2):

I believe I found the answer to my problems.  In my subdivision surface modifier I had view and render at different values.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, only after rendering the disabled Subdivision Surface Modifier, which had its visibility toggled off came back on with its View Settings. Thanks for posting, it was driving me nuts!